# In a game of tug of war, what concepts are involved in determining where the rope breaks?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, material-science

Assume that in a game of tug-of-war the rope ends up breaking.  What concepts/factors would contribute to the position of where the rope breaks?

Comment: the strength of a chain is it's weakest link

Comment: It is not newtonian mechanics but materials related. The rope will break where the resistance of an individual thread is smaller, due to some imperfection .That thread breaks, then the rest of the threads take up that portion of the force. A second one breaks, and the stress becomes bigger for all, until a collective effect depending on probabilities for that type of rope to have multiple breaks due to imperfections happen next to each other, or as the threads break individually the stress on the few remaining gets too big . It is not an algebraic problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oddly enough,  this basic question is addressed in one of the most well-known intro Physics texts (or at least, it was back in the 1970's editions, "the Great Eggplant" Halliday&Resnick).   They describe a long rope hanging vertically , with a large weight partway down. (think of a bell-pull).   Clearly the tension is greater above the weight because of the weight itself.  A long slow pull will break the rope near the top, but a short impulse pull will break the rope below the weight, basically because the rope snaps before it can transmit the tension along its full length.

Comment: @ja72  thanks, but credit goes to H&R  :-)